# Peer authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

At my VPS server, I do:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

But, I get this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-core-1.24.0/lib/fog/core/collection.rb:148: warning: circular argument reference - filters
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fog-1.23.0/lib/fog/rackspace/mock_data.rb:42: warning: duplicated key at line 80 ignored: "name"
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/simple_form-3.0.2/lib/simple_form/inputs/boolean_input.rb:38: warning: circular argument reference - unchecked_value
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myuser"
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:888:in `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:568:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:41:in `postgresql_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:435:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:445:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:416:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:351:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:350:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:541:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:909:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

database.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: mydatabase
  pool: 5
  username: myuser
  password: mypassword
```

What possible reason would this be? although myuser is the owner of mydatabase
How solve this?

Comment: add a host parameter to the database.yml file as well like host: localhost after password. See if that solves your issue.

Comment: I've fixed it by using trust at pg_hba.conf for local connections, is this safe?

Comment: Yes, its safe as you limited this for local connections only.